# How to resolve FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) using React components?

Tags: reactjs, fouc

As the title says, how do you guys solve FOUC problem with React components?
As my React components get mounted and componentDidMount handler gets called, I bind to various JQeuryUI widgets.
This is where the FOUC happens.

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694118/how-to-resolve-fouc-in-react-js/50727768#50727768

Answer (score 2):

1) Try rendering the DOM on the server side: https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

2) Try to not use jQuery plugins. Find or rewrite it in React. Here's a site that contains a lot of react components: http://react.rocks

Comment: "Try to not use jQuery plugins -> rewrite it in React.". It's Angular all over again. And in 3 years there is another player and we're doing this again... *sigh*

Comment: Welcome to the frontend world :-)

Comment: By using jQuery you're depending on a framework which doesn't necessarily play nice with others